Does anyone remember what happened to the experimental search for polynomial identities for $\pi$?
So a while back I was on the internet and had encountered a website containing an experimental search for identities for $\pi$.  My memory was that the page belonged to either Jonathan Sondow or Michael Somos, but now I am not sure (I don't even know if I trust my memory on the 'S' in the last name)  . The page most likely belongs to Jim Cullen and I have been wrongly attributing the open status of these identities to Gourevitch's conjecture (special thanks to Timothy Chow for reverse-engineering my brain and revealing this very unfortunate mental hash collision).
 Basically they had experimentally searched the space of identities of the form $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{P(n)}$ over a large number of polynomials $P(n)$ and used a tool like Munafo's RIES to see if they matched any known forms. They had struck gold finding some unusual identities involving either $\pi^2$ or $\pi^4$ with quadratic or quartic denominators (I don't remember which). These identities looked like they should be related to the riemann zeta function but the identities had no known proof/explanation at the time.
I want to:

find this website so at least I can edit this question and give the person due credit.

Ask what the state of those identities are. Do they remain open? 


I am very happy with the answers and comments this question has generated. I think other people interested in $\pi$ formulas will probably find this as a useful exploration point.
I assume Gourevitch's Conjecture  remains open although if anyone had updates on it they could post here or this more trafficked location

could this be PSLQ? https://www.davidhbailey.com/dhbpapers/pslq-comp-alg.pdf , see table 1.

Thanks for the tip! Let me explore Baileys page. I wonder if that is where I stumbled upon that day. It was an html page not a pdf specifically.

This experimental search is something that I have not attempted. Sorry.

Could you be thinking of https://www.ramanujanmachine.com/ ?

no i'm familiar with that project but it definitely would be of interest to anyone that finds the ideas close to this question interesting. Now that you remind me I do wonder if the folks behind that have considered looking at nested radicals or general other infinite function composition flavors.

@SidharthGhoshal As Jorge Zuniga has commented, Gourevitch's conjecture has now been proved. I have updated my answer to that other MO question accordingly.

I believe $\pi$ can be evaluated as sort of a recursive ratio of polynomials (see my answer to a question on a recursive formula for $\pi$).

I'm not aware of a perfect match to your description, but here are a few possibilities. Even if they are near-misses, perhaps they will help you with your search.
Jesús Guillera's webpage has a list of various identities involving $\pi$. See also his paper, About a new kind of Ramanujan-type series, Experimental Mathematics 12 (2003), 507–510.
Your mention of $\pi^4$ specifically is reminiscent of Cullen's $\pi^4$ formula. But I see you already know about Cullen's page.
Gert Almkvist is another name that comes to mind. See for example, Some new formulas for $\pi$, by Gert Almkvist, Christian Krattenthaler, and Joakim Petersson, Experimental Mathematics 12 (2003), 441–456.

This really might be it. My bad memory may have mixed up Gourevitch's conjecture with Cullen's formula and wrongly attributed it to Cullen's page. I will do a dive on wayback machine and see if theres a version of that page that also says "these identites are open". If not then maybe im fabricating this memory.

4 sources with state-of-art information about this topic on some recent Polynomial identities for $\pi^c$ are:
1.- "Rational Hypergeometric Ramanujan Identities for $1/π^c$: Survey and Generalizations" (2021) arXiv:2101.12592 by J. Guillera and H. Cohen.
2.- There is also a connection of Hypergeometric Motives for some $1/\pi^2$ identities to Hilbert Modular Forms in this work "Special Hypergeometric Motives and Their L-Functions: Asai Recognition" by : Lassina Dembélé, Alexei Panchishkin, John Voight & Wadim Zudilin (2020).  Experimental Mathematics, DOI: 10.1080/10586458.2020.1737990
3.- K.C. Au takes the Wilf Zeilberger method to another level for proving some long time conjectured $\pi^c$ hypergeometric-type identities with $c=-3,-4,4$. Kam Cheong Au. "Wilf-Zeiberger Seeds and Non-Trivial Hypergeometric Identities". (Dec.2023) arXiv:2312.14051v2
Proofs of Cullen's, Guillera's, Zhao's, Gourevitch, Zhi-Wei Sun  identities, among others, are found in this work.
4.- Jesus Guillera once said that he thought all Ramanujan-type Pi formulas, could be eventually proven by means of the WZ algorithm.  Inspired on this, and on 2.- and 3.- as well, I have recently placed a question here in MO since I think there should be a link between Hypergeometric Motives (the connection to L-functions and Modular forms) and the WZ algorithm. I think this topic has not already been deeply studied .
At the end of this question, in the EXAMPLES section, I have placed some recently found and proven (Apr. 2024) $\pi^{±4}$ and $\zeta(5)$ new hypergeometric-type identities.

To follow up on my comment, the specific experimental search for polynomial identities that relate powers of $\pi$ and values of the Riemann zeta function, is in Experimental Evaluation of Euler Sums by Bailey, Borwein, and Girgensohn.
A conjectured identity is
$$\zeta(5)=Z_5\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^5{2k\choose k}},\;\;Z_5\in\mathbb{Q},$$
which if correct would nicely complement identities for $\zeta(2)=3\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2{2k\choose k}}$, $\zeta(3)=\tfrac{5}{2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^3{2k\choose k}}$, and $\zeta(4)=\tfrac{36}{17}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^4{2k\choose k}}$.

"Conjectured identity" is probably the wrong term since their main point is to present evidence against such an identity. For more recent work along these lines, see Simultaneous Generation of Koecher and Almkvist-Granville's Apéry-Like Formulae by Rivoal, Experiment. Math. 13(4): 503-508 (2004).
